# Function that gives you common divisors for two given integers

Tags: python

How to write a function that returns a list of all common divisors for two integers except 1. I've tried this:

```py
x = 
y = 
L = []
for n in range(min(x,y)1):
    if x%n == y%n == 0:
        L.append(n)
        print(L)
```

Comment: Other than multiple syntax errors, what's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: Okay, and what happens when you try the code? How is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: @alirezafnatica That's Java, not Python.

Comment: Please note that you're [expected](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) to at least *try* to debug the code on your own prior to posting here.

Answer (score 0):

First use Euclid's algorithm to find the greatest common divisor.

Then determine the prime factorization of the GCD (if your numbers aren't too large, this can be done by successive divisions).

Finally, generate all tuples of multiplicities of the prime factors, from 0 to their value in the GCD and compute the corresponding integer.

E.g. for 60 and 84, the GCD is 12 = 2².3. Then the common divisors are 1x1=1, 1x3=3, 2x1=2, 2x3=6, 2²=4, 2²x3=12, given by the multiplicities (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1).

Comment: This is a better answer than those on the duplicate, so you should move it there. Maybe add the `itertools` code for the second part.